# two column layout using XSLT of People Search Core Result WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-designer

I have implemented "Employee Directory" on my portal using People Search Core Result Webpart. I want to create two column layout to display the results. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataView web part to help you style your search results.

Here an example of the exact same exercise, perfectly valid under SP 2010/2007

http://techdhaan.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/moss-2007-employee-directory-web-part-using-search-and-data-view-web-parts/

Answer (score 1):

In your XSLT you can use a `[position()mod 2=1]` predicate to select results for the first column and then use `following-sibling::*` to select the corresponding result for the second columns.

See [Producing a two-column, side-by-side view with XSL](http://www.tonymarston.net/xml-xsl/two-column-view.html)